# How to config a appropriate converter to spring MVC controller method?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am try to understand message converter of spring MVC.
when I added the json related dependencies into classpath, and added annotation @ResponseBody to the controller method I got the json response,

And then I added the xml related dependencies into classpath, the got the xml response as expected.

But after all above dependencies added into classpath and I want to make one http call response with json format and the another one response with xml format.

What should be done?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question with it. (For instance add some code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically one of the options is `Accept` Header, but spring has a built-in mechanism to deal with requirement like this called `Content negotiation`, you can config your own config or use the standard spring config, checkout this article for further information: https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

When deciding in which data format to respond, spring will take the "Accept"-Header into account.

So if you make an HTTP call to one of your spring methods and you have `Accept: application/json` in your header, spring should respond with a JSON response. Use `Accept: application/xml` or `Accept: text/xml` for an XML response.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is part of what Jaiwo answered me. So I accepted his.